# How to add a block in sidebar of Magento blog?

Tags: magento

Can anyone help me out of this Question

I have a blog in Magento with a block displaying all the categories added from the admin. Say I have something like this -

```
**Blog Categories**
________________________

Category 1
Category 2
Category 3
```

Now, I want to add another block below it which would pull posts from a specific category. Something like this-

```
Category 1
________________________

Post 1
Post 2
Post 3
```

Can anyone guide me, How could I do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have template for your posts, you can insert them below layered navigation. create local.xml in your layout directory.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
  <reference name="left_first">
    <block type="core/template" name="mine" template="custom/post.phtml"/>
  </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Now your'e post's will be seen below the layered navigation.